# Multiple Factor Analysis with FactoMineR: problem when one active group of variables only

Tags: r, factor-analysis

**Context:** I want to run a MFA on a data-table where one group of variables only is active, the others being supplementary.
*Example:* I indeed want to study if the spread of observations can be explained by their belonging to one or the other supplementary group. (Say that I want to study if the physiological and the nationality of participants impact their taste. `taste_OJ` and `taste_AJ` correspond to the qualitative evaluation of orange juice and apple juice, respectively. These evaluations are used to determine the profile of my observations and thus construct the space. I want to observe if following qualitative groups can explain spread of observation: Group 1 is `Physio`, constituted of `Physio_Size` and `Physio_Sex`; Group2 is `Nat` constituted of `Nationalities` only.)

**Issue:** However, when running my `R`'s `FactoMineR` script, I get following error:

> `Error in res.mfa$group$coord[, axes, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Thank [this question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43728411/5433628), I tracked down my issue as being the following: I have one active group (constituted of multiple variables) only.

**Question:** Is it ok to run a MFA with one group of active variables only?

*Related question:* How to make the code below run without error (-;

---

```
taste_OJ <- c("sweet","sweet","sweet","salty")
taste_AJ <- c("bitter","sour","bitter","bitter")
Physio_Size <- c("big","small","big","big")
Physio_Sex <- c("F","M","F","M")
Nationalies <- c("AFG","ZWE","ZWE","ZWE")
df <- data.frame(taste_OJ, taste_AJ, Physio_Size, Physio_Sex, Nationalies)
library(FactoMineR)
res <- MFA(base = df, group = c(2,1,2), type = c("n","n","n"), name.group = c("active", "Physio","Nat"), num.group.sup = c(2,3))
```

Comment: So, what is the difference between the one explanatory variable and all the others which are also explanatory? :->

Comment: @January My question was indeed unclear, because I mixed up "explanatory" and "active" variables. I have rephrased it all now. Basically, one group only is active (i.e. used to construct the space), and the others are explanatory. I want to study if the spread of observations can be explained by their belonging to one or the other explanatory group.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I understand "active variable" is a jargon meaning essentially a variable included in the analysis (as opposed to a variable not included in the analysis, which is called "supplementary"). In this sense, the terms "explanatory" and "active" are not exclusive. In fact, in an MFA, you don't have other variables than explanatory (except for the sample ID perhaps). My response below stands; also, you still have not provided a code example which produces the first error you are asking about.

Comment: Also, since you seem to have problems with programming, consider moving the question to stackoverflow first.

Comment: @January I used "explanatory" as synonym of "supplementary". I changed it I order to make things more obvious. Regarding code example, the MWE provided at the end of the question does produce the error mentionned (at least by me).

Comment: @January My question is not that much regarding programming: the above example works if you create one group for each active variable (i.e. `res2 <- MFA(base = df, group = c(1,1,1,2), type = c("n","n","n","n"), name.group = c("active1", "active2", "Physio","Nat"), num.group.sup = c(3,4))`). My question is thus: *why doesn't it work when I have one group of active variables only?*

Comment: First, you give an error message. Then, you produce an example which does not result in that error message. In any case, if you only have one group of variables, then MFA is not the method to use, I don't think there is much to discuss.

Comment: @January I'm not sure to understand your point: The example above [*does*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM0Tv.png) returns the error I mentionned. (Maybe we don't have same configuration?) Then my question is *"Is it ok to run a MFA with one group of active variables only?"*: I think this is the point to discuss. You say that MFA is not the method to use: this is then an answer, I'd be glad you to post. If you provide details about *why* it isn't appropriate, and *which other method* should be used in order to address my global problem (2nd sentence of the question), I would be more than pleased.